# Кэширование SQL запросов PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Я понимаю, что кэшировать лучше блоками конкретные вещи. Но бывают проекты, например на какой-нибудь CMS. И некогда вычислять где что лагает, хочется быстрым решением решить проблемы с нагрузкой на бд. Причем в CMS обычно очень много SELECT в таблицы, которые либо редко меняются, либо вообще не меняются. И бывает по несколько раз за один запрос к странице.

Есть ли возможность быстро внедрить кэширование в запросов? Как например в hibernate у Java?

Встроенное кэширование mysql все пишут, что плохое. Как же тогда сделать нечто универсальное, чтобы облегчить жизнь mysql?

Конечно можно самому написать это, но много обработчиков понадобится, чтобы очищать когда происходит insert/update/delete. Не нашёл почему-то лучших практик для реализации кэширования sql запросов на php.

Comment: В БД используется кэширование данных, оно достаточно специфическое и может не подходить под определенные условия. Вы рассматривали сторонние кэш-сервисы типа memcached? Опять-таки, не до конца понятны ваши требование к процессу, приведите хотя бы примеры вашего кэширования. Стоит учитывать что при кэшировании важнейший параметр - это свежесть и актуальность данных, как вы его будете обрабатывать?

Comment: Я рассматривал кэширование в Redis. Вопрос как это на стороне PHP сделать, потому что отслеживать чистку такого кэша это не просто

Comment: Куда и как вы будете писать и складывать кэш, это уже ваше, а суть кэширования скорее всего и так ясна, то есть вы не можете для себя распознать тригеры для очистки кэша и ситуации, когда данные нужно будет снова закэшировать. Задача если честно не ясна, возможно вам поможет крон, для всех статичных данных, проследите какую-то статистику, как часто меняются те или иные данные, кэшируйте, очиста по планировщику + проверки или колл-бэки, на ванжые данные при несоотвествие чего-то с чем-то.